# android things on Rpi 3 - Bluetooth LE peripheral role?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-things

Is Bluetooth LE peripheral role supported on Android Things/RPi3?

Trying to run this, get "Bluetooth LE peripheral is not supported on this device"

Comment: Please be more specific with the code you are trying to run. In general, yes, GATT Server and Advertisements are supported in Android Things, allowing a peripheral device.